# I'm getting TypeError: Cannot call method 'slice' of undefined when loading data from factory ng-Table AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I'm new to AngularJS and got stucked in displaying the data when using ng-Table coming from a service. I'm getting an error

TypeError: Cannot call method 'slice' of undefined
    at Object.$scope.tableParams.ngTableParams.getData (index.html:122:32)

When i hard-coded the json data values it work just fine. I think the data from the factory contained more than just the json data result hence the problem with the slicing.

My controller looks like this:

```
myApp.controller('usersCtrl', function usersCtrl($scope, userData, $filter, ngTableParams, $log){

    userData.getUsers(function(users){
        $scope.users = users;
    })

    var users = $scope.users;

    $scope.$watch("filter.$", function () {
        $scope.tableParams.reload();
    });

    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1,            // show first page
        count: 10,          // count per page
        sorting: {
            name: 'asc'     // initial sorting
        }
    }, {
        getData: function($defer, params) {
            var filteredData = $filter('filter')(users, $scope.filter);
            var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                                $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) :
                                filteredData;

            $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
        },
        $scope: $scope
    });

});
```

Then my factory service is this:

```
myApp.factory('userData', function($http, $log){
    return {
        getUsers: function(successcb){
            $http({method: 'GET', url: 'api/users'}).
                success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                    successcb(data);
                    $log.warn(data, status, headers, config);
                }).
                error(function(data, status, headers, config){
                    $log.warn(data, status, headers, config);
                });
        }
    }
});
```

My HTML is this :

```
<div class="row">
    <div>
        <p>Filter: <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="filter.$" /></p>

        <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
            <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
                <td data-title="'Name'" sortable="name">
                    {{user.name}}
                </td>
                <td data-title="'Age'" sortable="'age'">
                    {{user.age}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to resolve `$defer` within table `getData` after the ajax has completed. As it stands right now if you were to log `filteredData` to console, it will be undefined, thus it can't be sliced.

Try moving `userData.getUsers` to:

```
getData: function ($defer, params) {
     /* make ajax call */
    userData.getUsers(function(users) {
        /* now we have data to work with*/
        $scope.users = users;

        var filteredData = $filter('filter')(users, $scope.filter);
        var orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) : filteredData;
        /* and can resolve table promise  */
        $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));

    })

}
```

Comment: o glory did this help me out; Thank you